# Azure function template

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

When I create Azure function it is by default referencing .net core 2.1; I remember in the past it was referencing .net standard 2.0

Question: What is better to be referencing right now and why such change happened? I tend to think that .net standard is better since I do not see any core-specific feature to be used by  a function. What am I missing?

Comment: So you are creating azure function v2? change to 2.0 should be no problem.

Comment: yes, changing is not a problem. But I want to understand why MS suggests to use .net core 2.1 instead of standard

Comment: Before October 2018, .net standard 2.0 was used. After that, .net core 2.1 is referenced by default. Both of them can work.

Comment: If you don't need to use .net core API. you can stay with .net standard 2.0. That is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

.net core 2.1 is the latest template. The template used before October 2018 is .net standard 2.0. Both frameworks work. Function v2 is based on the .net core environment from the beginning. Changes to the framework will not affect previously built functions, but you need to provide access to the .Net Core API and related dependencies.

The only problem is that you can't reference projects that target different frameworks, and they won't be compatible without changing TF. It is recommended that you use .net core 2.1 to ensure long-term compatibility.